# Internet speak - orz

Tags: internet-slang

I've seen several of my Japanese friends use "orz" in various types of posts on Facebook.  What does "orz" mean?  It's driving me nuts!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#Orz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lol, sorry I often use it too... when I want to show that I'm shocked, sad or depressed...it's like OMG or something similar to it I think... because doesn't it look like someone throwing himself on the ground?

Comment: No, not at all.  So you mean it's like a 顔文字 or something?

Comment: @istrasci san... Yes that's what I heard... The letter 'o' shows the head and 'z' shows the legs. And have you seen ノシ too?

Comment: No, I've never seen ノシ either.  What is that?  Japanese people have very.....unique...imaginations.

Comment: @istrasci san, ノシ=Bye. (Looks like hands being waved good-bye, no?)

Comment: AH! It totally does! orz!

Comment: @Chocolate:  No, this is a hand waving -->  ,\\\  Active imaginations I tell you.

Comment: @Chocolate:  I get it now, after seeing rio's picture in the link.  You should have said it was a ひれ伏【ふ】した pose.  I was imagining a 倒【たお】れた pose, like he was lying on his back, or a 横【よこ】たわった pose.

Comment: getting a bit off-topic, but I think the `チラ` in `|ω・｀)ﾁﾗｯ` might be similar to `ノシ` :P

Comment: @cypher san... チラッ is an imitative word for taking a glance, no? Like...チラリと見る.

Comment: @Chocolate:  親指　→ 　,\\\  ←　other 指.  other指は斜めだから、wavingです。

Answer (score 5):

orz

"o" is for head, "r" for arm and body, and "z" for body and legs.
I couldn't find any pictures of it, but found a picture of its variety "OTL".

http://hehehe.be/blog/2008/12/20/otl/

Comment: Lol, 'hehehe'...! This is so funny~~!

Comment: AAHHHH!!!  That picture made so much more sense.  It's a side profile!  Even with @Chocolate's description in his answer, I didn't really understand the pose it was trying to convey.